# Oracle - How to encode a string as a number and retrieve the original string from that number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to encode a string as a number and retrieve the original string from that number with another function. It only needs to support ascii characters between 0 and 255, not unicode. The number can be integer or float.

Was thinking of multiplying the ascii value by the position and 256 and then adding the result, but not sure if this will work.

The length of the string can be up to 240 characters.

The intended use is to convert a string value to a number value for use in machine learning algorithms; since lots of machine learning algorithms require a numeric value instead of a string value.

Comment: Why would you do that? In any case you need a byte for each character. You won't get far with this method.

Comment: Need a quick function to convert a string to number for machine learning purposes.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/. I suggest closing this question and open a new post with the real question.

Comment: Additional information provided as per comments.

Comment: @Superdooperhero: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function str2num
(
   p_string in varchar2
)  return number is

l_i      number(15);
l_c      number(15);
l_answer number(38);

begin

   l_answer := 0;
   for l_i in 1..length(p_string) loop
      l_c := ascii(substr(p_string, l_i, 1));
      l_answer := l_answer + (l_c * power(2, (l_i - 1) * 8));
   end loop;

   return l_answer;

end str2num;
```

Can only handle 52 characters, but good enough. Now the question is, what is the opposite function.

Comment: Supposing your string is : ABC     
A=65, B=66, C = 67     

CodeNum = 65+66*256+67*256*256=4407873     

4407873/(256*256) = 67 ----> C     
4407873 % (256*256) = 16961     
16961 / 256 = 66 ---> B     
16961 % 256 = 65 ---> A     
     
As I told you before, I don't think you can "codify" more then 4 or five characters (overflow numeric)

Comment: A 240 character string encoded this way will far exceed the capacity of an Oracle `NUMBER`.  240^256 ~= 7e+608.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming starting position is 1:

ASCII VALUE * 256^(Position - 1)

How long can be the string?  The numeric value can tend to be very high!

If strings your are speaking about are "limited" (in number) and repetitive (es. words or sentences) you can write them in a table (id bigint, descr VARCHAR(240) ) and use the id as the number.  What do you think?

Comment: The string can be 240 characters in length

Comment: As you can imagine, the number can be too large!

Comment: Writing it to a table is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I think etsa might be on to something here, except the formula is probably ASCII_VALUE*2^(Position - 1)

Comment: @Superdooper: I think it is 256^ and not 2^ (in a binary positional numerical system it's 2^, but in this case it's like a 256 numerical system, ie a system with 256 different symbol.  In system with ten different symbols, you have 10^ - our usual decimal numerical system)